# Trying to get the results of division equation to two decimal places in out put?

Tags: python, decimal, division, equation

So I just did a simple file for Covid deaths in Canada, and I can;t seem to get the decimals places down to two in the out put after a division?

```
import datetime as dt
start_date = dt.date(2020, 3, 9)
end_date = dt.date(2020, 5, 18)
date_td = end_date - start_date

days_between = date_td.days
print(days_between, 'Days since first Covid death in Canada')
# March 3, 2020 was first recorded death in Canada.  70 days
total_deaths = 5805 / 70
print(total_deaths,':' 'Total Deaths in Canada per day')
carehome_deaths = 4702 / 70
print(carehome_deaths,':' 'Total Care Home deaths per day')

outside_deaths = 1103 / 70
print(outside_deaths,':' 'Total deaths outside of care homes per day')
```

Output:

70 Days since first Covid death in Canada
82.92857142857143 :Total Deaths in Canada per day
67.17142857142858 :Total Care Home deaths per day
15.757142857142858 :Total deaths outside of care homes per day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To round a decimal in your print statement, do the following:

```
print(round(total_deaths, 2), "....")
```

You can find more info about built-in datatype here [round()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round)

Answer (score 1):

use `round(total_deaths, 2)`, Hope this Helps!

Comment: yes, you gave me the same answer!  :)   but it works..Thanks  All the best